# Tips and tricks for abs

Tags: muscle, abdominals

I'm new to this and am looking for a good way to get abs. Does anybody know some fast exercises that could help me?

Comment: This StackExchance is positively overflowing with questions and answers pertaining to the visibility and maintenance of abs. I suggest reading a few of them that have relevant titles, and asking some more specific questions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Leg raises, sit ups, planks, crunches, and knee raises. For abs, most important thing is the right diet plan, so no sugars and junks and those 5 exercises two times a week will make those abs to show up.

Comment: This is a good plan if you'd like to completely neglect the external obliques, serratus anterior, the iliac crest and more. All the exercises you mentioned work in the median and parasaggital planes, and ignore the coronal and axial planes.

Answer (score 5):

There's no “magic” set of exercises to get great abs.  That's because great abs are a result of genetics, proper nutrition, and a long commitment to hard work.  Each of of has one or more body parts that are stubborn, or, lack the degree of improvement we seek.  The only proven technique is committing to a regular exercise program that works the entire body, and, resisting any urge to quit when results don't come as quick as desired.

Comment: +1 for promoting discipline over shortcuts and tunnel vision mindsets. Fitness should be approached holistically, and not with a magnifying glass.